# Does every client in group chat application acts as a server in udp?

Tags: udp, client-server

I am trying to build a group chat application using UDP. One of the client sends a request to the server
and server replies the same message to all the clients in the group. Same like whatsApp group chat. I am confused whether each client behaves as a server or should there be a single server which send the message to all the clients. I have searched over the internet, I couldn't found the answer and so I am asking here and I felt it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive UDP traffic you have to be a "server". UDP is connection-less. There are no clients or servers. In order to receive you have to open a port.